# Cant install SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows, sql-server-2019, windows-10

[image]I have a single node Windows 10 Pro machine, 64 bit, with 32GB Ram and an i7 processor. When I try to install the developer edition of Sql Server 2019, it fails installing the Database engine with a security permissions issue. I am the only user of my machine and I am in the Administrators group. I run the installation as Administrator and I have removed all other versions of SQL. I tried installing with the machine in safe mode, but you are not allowed. I have also disabled all antivirus and firewalls, but it always fails for the same reason.

Has anybody had this issue and managed to overcome it. My windows 10 has all the latest updates.

initial message:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup
>
> ---
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel
> this action and continue setup.
>
> For help, click:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%25400xBB814387

The link is no help at all.

The full error log :

> ```
>  Overall summary:   
>   Final result:                Failed: see details below   
>   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551   
>   Start time:                    2020-07-27 11:37:51   
>   End time:                      2020-07-27 11:51:28   
>   Requested action:              Install
>  
>  Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
>  information for those features:   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use
>  the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this
>  feature, and then run the setup process again.
>  
>  
>  Machine Properties:  
>   Machine name:                  DESKTOP-18RMQ5J  
>   Machine processor count:       8  
>   OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19041)   OS service pack:              
>   OS region:                     United States  
>   OS language:                   English (United Kingdom)   
>   OS architecture:               x64  
>   Process architecture:          64 Bit   
>   OS clustered:                  No
>  
>  Product features discovered:   
>  Product              Instance          Instance ID                    Feature                                Language             Edition              Version         Clustered Configured
>  
>  
>  Package properties:  
>   Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2019   
>   ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019  
>   Type:                          RTM   
>   Version:                       15   
>   SPLevel:                       0   
>   Installation location:         H:\x64\setup\   
>   Installation edition:          Developer
>   Product Update Status:         None discovered.
>  
>  User Input Settings:  
>   ACTION:                        Install  
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false  
>   AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLAgent$VISUALSERVER   
>   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****   
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual   
>   ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup   
>   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS  
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   
>   ASDATADIR:                     Data   
>   ASLOGDIR:                      Log   
>   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1   
>   ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR   
>   ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>   
>   ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>   
>   ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   
>   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>   
>   ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>   
>   ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>  
>   ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   
>   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   
>   CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>   
>   CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>   
>   CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0   
>   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>   
>   CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>   
>   CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>  
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   
>   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0  
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0   
>   CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\SetupBootstrap\Log\20200727_113748\ConfigurationFile.ini   
>   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0   
>   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>   
>   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>   
>   CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>   
>   ENABLERANU:                    false   
>   ENU:                           true   
>   EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>   
>   EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>   
>   FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, SDK   
>   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0  
>   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>   
>   FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>   
>   FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>   
>   HELP:                          false   
>   IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false  
>   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false   
>   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true   
>   IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false   
>   INDICATEPROGRESS:              false   
>   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\   
>   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   
>   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>  
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ 
>   INSTANCEID:                    VISUALSERVER   
>   INSTANCENAME:                  VISUALSERVER   
>   ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   
>   ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>   
>   ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391   
>   ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>  
>   ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic   
>   ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>   
>   ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service 
>   ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>   
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   
>   ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>   
>   ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>   
>   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   
>   ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   
>   ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty> 
>   ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>   
>   ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>   
>   ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic  
>   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0   
>   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>   
>   MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>   
>   MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
>   NPENABLED:                     0   
>   PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>   
>   PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>  
>   PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   
>   PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>   
>   PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>  
>   PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   
>   PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>   
>   PBSCALEOUT:                    false   
>   PID:                           *****   
>   QUIET:                         false   
>   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   
>   ROLE:                             
>   RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode   
>   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>  
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>   
>   RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   
>   SAPWD:                         <empty>   
>   SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>   
>   SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>   
>   SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS   
>   SQLJAVADIR:                    <empty>  
>   SQLMAXDOP:                     8   
>   SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647   
>   SQLMINMEMORY:                  0   
>   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$VISUALSERVER   
>   SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false  
>   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>   
>   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic   
>   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-18RMQ5J\willi  
>   SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$VISUALSERVER  
>   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>   
>   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic   
>   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>  
>   SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8   
>   SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64  
>   SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8   
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>   
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64   
>   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8   
>   SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>   
>   SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>   
>   SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false  
>   SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false   
>   TCPENABLED:                    0   
>   UIMODE:                        Normal   
>   UpdateEnabled:                 true   
>   UpdateSource:                  MU   
>   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false   
>   USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false   
>   X86:                           false
>  
>    Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200727_113748\ConfigurationFile.ini
>  
>  Detailed results:   
>   Feature:                       Database Engine
>   Services   Status:             Failed   
>   Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.   
>   Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.  
>   Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services
>  Instance Features   
>   Component error code:          0x84BB0001   
>   Error description:             Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.   
>   Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387
>  
>   Feature:                       Client Tools SDK   
>   Status:                        Passed
>  
>  Rules with failures or warnings:
>  
>   Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200727_113748\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
> ```

When I look in the configcheck report, I see a warning that it thinks firewall is enabled. I first disable them via BullGuard, then because I disable here, it automatically starts the Defender etc. So I turn those off as well. Not sure why it still thinks firewall is still on. All other checks pass.

Comment: "a security permissions issue" - the full error message would probably be useful here.

Comment: @PeterB I'll try and track the log down and post it

Comment: A quick google of the error message results in a few suggestions that antivirus might be interfering with the installation. Have you tried with your AV software temporarily disabled?

Comment: Check the setup logs for specifics of the failed operation. The logs are located in the latest timestamped folder name under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log`.

Comment: ...click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and **continue** setup

Comment: What's your feathers need in SQL server... I guess you choose not recommended options like polybase .

Comment: @Amirhossein. I just accepted the defaults. But was just trying to install the DB Engine and the ClientSDK. SDK installs no issue. I've also not installed SSMS yet either.

Comment: DB engine just need dot net farmwork 3.5 and 4 or upper. First check install dot net.

Comment: @Amirhossein I have the latest Visual Studio Pro installed.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548757/attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation-when-executing-sql-server-2019-se

Answer (score 1):

## Generic Answer

This answer applies to all installation issues with SQL Server. It is a generic answer describing the steps required to analyse further details.

### SQL Server Setup Routine Logging

When you installed SQL Server 2019 a detailed (very verbose) setup log was created in a sub-directory like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\VVV\Setup Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS\Detail.txt
```

- `VVV` = SQL Server Version

  - 100 = SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2
  - 110 = SQL Server 2012 / 2012 R2
  - 120 = SQL Server 2014
  - 130 = SQL Server 2016
  - 140 = SQL Server 2017
  - 150 = SQL Server 2019
- `YYYYMMDD` = Date the installation occurred

  - e.g. `20200727`
- `HHMMSS` = Time the installation occurred

  - e.g. `110523`

An actual path would be:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20200727_110523\Detail.txt
                                       ^                         ^        ^
                                       |                         |        |
              SQL Server 2019      ----+                         |        | 
              July 27th, 2020      ------------------------------+        |
              11.05am (23 seconds) ---------------------------------------+
```

### Detail.txt

The `Detail.txt` will contain a detailed description at or around the time of failure.

#### Example Failure / Error / Exception

A section where a failure occurs will look similar to this:

> ```
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Running Action: ProcessUpdateParametersAction
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Product Update Status:
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:   User selected not to include product updates.
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:   Error message:
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchException
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:     Message: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         SQL Server setup failed to search for product updates. This may indicate that the Windows Update service does not have online access to the Microsoft Update server or Windows Server Update Services.
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:     HResult : 0x85190003
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1305 (519)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         ErrorCode : 3 (0003)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:     Data: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:       WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchException@3
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:     Stack: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchUtility.TrySearch(String serviceId, String query)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchEngine.Search(String serviceId, String query)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSetupSearchEngine.SearchUpdates()
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.SearchUpdatesAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:     Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.WuaUpdateSearchException
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         Message: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                 Failed to search for updates with query 'CategoryIDs contains '6F210755-A742-449E-A57D-E459E20596C8''. Error: Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80240438
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         HResult : 0x85170004
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                 FacilityCode : 1303 (517)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                 ErrorCode : 4 (0004)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         Data: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:           Query = CategoryIDs contains '6F210755-A742-449E-A57D-E459E20596C8'
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:           ErrorMessage = Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80240438
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:           WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.WuaUpdateSearchException@4
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         Stack: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.WuaUpdateSearcher.Search(Int32 timeout, String criteria)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.MuSearchUtility.Search(String serviceId, String query)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:         Inner exception type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:             Message: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                         Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80240438
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:             HResult : 0x80240438
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:             Stack: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Interop.WUApiLib.IUpdateSearcher.EndSearch(ISearchJob searchJob)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp:                         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SmartSetupExtension.WuaUpdateSearcher.Search(Int32 timeout, String criteria)
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: 
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Completed Action: ProcessUpdateParametersAction, returned True
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteDownloadSetupUpdatesWorkflow, returned True
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteOuterSetupStartUI, returned True
> (01) 2020-06-17 13:11:20 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

In this case, the error that occurred had no impact on the installation as the availability of the online update check is not a prerequisite.

### Finding the Error Code

In your case, you should be able to find the error code `0x84BB0001` by opening the `Detail.txt` installation log file in an editor of your choice and searching for the code.

Depending on what you find, you will have to:

- Grant permissions to registry
- Remove components
- Install certain components
- ....

## Educated Guess to your specific issue

As you pointed out in the comments, you already have **Visual Studio** installed. This has been known to cause issues during the installation of SQL Server xxxx depending on the version used.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 20xx Redistributable (x86)** and **Microsoft Visual C++ 20xx Redistributable (x64)** are also known to cause issues, when installing a lower version of SQL Server.

E.g. installing **SQL Server 2016** on a **Windows Server 2016** where **Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86)** has been installed will halt the installation.

### Possible Solution(s)

- De-install Visual Studio after saving your settings.
- De-install any Visual C++ 20xx Redistributable that has a higher version than the SQL Server Version you are installing
- De-install the **Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit)** setup program before you try a re-install.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will work through your suggestions

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. I worked through these, but nothing changes with regard to the error message I'm getting. As of today 12 March 2021, I've still not been able to install sql server 2019. I've given up and gone to Oracle.